# How to adjust position of body with collapsed margins

Tags: html, css

Here's an annoying little CSS quirk.  I'm wondering if someone could help me solve it.

### Disclaimer

I am not asking why this happens.  I am asking if there is a simple solution to this simple problem.  Thank you.

### Original Question (related to collapsed margins)

Basically: the `body` tag will **start** within the **content-box** of the first child, and not the **border-box**!  So, if your first child is a header tag (say, an `h1`), then the `body` tag's top position will begin **within the `h1`** (and JavaScript's `getBoundingClientRect` confirms that).

Simple question is how can you simply avoid this behavior, with CSS?

#### A Basic Example

**If** `body` is `position: relative`, and has first or last children with top/bottom margins, **then** an absolutely positioned element won't reach the top (or bottom).

```css
body {
  background: #222;
  position: relative;
}

#backdrop {
  background: rgba(150, 255, 255, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

#bottom-buster {
  height: 110vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="backdrop"></div>
<h1>Inner Margin Problem</h1>
<p>Why doesn't the backdrop reach the top of the page?</p>
<p>How do you solve the problem, without altering margins or positions?</p>
<p>Make sure you solve <b>the problem at the bottom of the page too.</b></p>
<div id="bottom-buster"></div>
<h2>What do you do about this H2?</h2>
```

Here's a codepen link to the problem: https://codepen.io/bozdoz/pen/GxNVPv?editors=1100

Here are some solutions (but I find them too obtrusive/specific):

You can reach the top of the page by setting `#backdrop` `top: 0` and removing `position: relative` from the `body`; but then the backdrop won't reach the bottom. You can then add `position: relative` to the `html` instead, and it should reach the top and bottom of the page.

Here are what I see as potential problems to the above solution: What if other elements on the page requires the `body` to have `position: relative`?  What if some other script/stylesheet has set the `height` of `html` to `100%`?

**One more time, to be clear**: Is there a more reliable way to have the `body` tag **begin** at the border-box of its first child, instead of its content-box?

Thanks! :D

Comment: you know its the margins on the `h1` and `h2` that creates the space correct?

Comment: I believe I covered that by saying the body starts at the content-box and not the border-box (i.e. `h1` margin is above the `body`)

Comment: Check out this. I did some html and body reset. https://codepen.io/bahiirwa/pen/NYdWxq?editors=1100#0

Comment: I still see the top margin in that example @omukiguy

Comment: `body {float: left; width: 100%;}` is 1 solution...keeps the margin aswell.

Comment: I've got a much better solution, but because this was marked as a duplicate, it won't let me answer.

Comment: well that is sad!

Comment: @bozdoz You can still post an answer to the other question...

Comment: @MrLister if by the other question you mean the one which is claimed to be "an exact duplicate" of this one, then I don't think it's appropriate, because (1) it has already been answered, and (2) my solution to my question doesn't address any of the questions posed in the other question. Thanks for your interest, and maybe help by voting to reopen. :D

Comment: @bozdoz Sorry, but the final question in your edited post misses the point: the location of the body's border-box is the same as its content-box, since it has neither a border nor a padding. So this location is not at the top of the window. The problem is the margin, and if you don't want to remove the body's margin, what you CAN do is remove all the margins in the #backdrop (replace them by paddings if need be) and then you can position the backdrop wherever you want, e.g. with `top:-8px` for the top of the window. Also, make the height 100vh instead of 100%.

Comment: @MrLister perhaps I didn't use the proper terminology, but my question is clearly different than the supposed duplicate.  And you are on to something with your statement that it has neither a border nor padding.  A good solution could be simply related to that.